# PostgreSQL создание копии базы данных через pgAdmin win11 x64

Tags: postgresql

Я пытаюсь сделать копию базы данных через pgAdmin (через командную строку не получается).
Меня интересуют только исходные данные (таблицы, связи).
При создании копии все настройки оставляю по-умолчанию.
[image: Параметры резервной копии]

Далее я создаю пустую базу данных с настройками по-умолчанию.
Восстановление провожу также с настройками по-умолчанию.

[image: Настройки при восстановлении]

```
Восстановление проходит с ошибками:
    pg_restore: ������: could not execute query: ОШИБКА: роль "***" не существует
    *** - имя пользователя, под которым я подключался к базе данных
```

Как избежать данной ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Завести в этом пустом кластере БД роль с именем, которое было в старом кластере БД, дать этой роли права на подключение к БД, на создание отношений и на полный доступ к ним.
Точнее не подскажу, поскольку без понятия, с какими параметрами pgadmin снимает дамп с базы и что у вас в итоге попало в дамп.